# Best practices for SKProductsRequest()

Tags: ios, asynchronous, storekit

I wonder when is the best time to call `SKProductsRequest()` to retrieve available products from App Store? I'm currently call it in the application business logic code where user needs to purchase the product to proceed. However, as the function call is asynchronous, it requires to split the application business code into pieces and move some of them to completion handler (called by `productsRequest(_:didReceived)`). I really want to avoid that. So I'm thinking to call this funciton in `application(:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions)` instead. It's almost certainly true that the call completes before user needs to purchase any item in the app. The disadvantage, however, is that the app always makes a call to App Store, even if user doesn't need to purchase. But the benefit is huge: the code is much easier to understood and maintain. I wonder how you guys call the function in your apps?

Comment: I would retrieve the products as soon as your app launches.  You should also instantiate your payment queue listener as soon as your app launches in order to handle any pending purchases.

Comment: Thanks for confirmation, Paul. I have changed my code that way. BTW, the approach has one subtle issue with iPhones sold in China, which prompt user to give permission when an app accesses networks for the first time (this is a China mainland only feature, I believe). So, although my app doesn't transfer any data over network except for accessing App Store, it asks for network permission as soon as it starts. That's bad. It would be good if iOS has a daemon for App Store communication and apps accesses it through IPC instead of direct network access.